# Git ignores config/database.php in Laravel

Tags: php, git, laravel-5

I have a fresh installation of Laravel 5.1 and just set up forge + digitalOcean + bitbucket workflow.

I tried to deploy my app using this setup. Everything went smoothly until I got Laravel error saying something like: `Database[] not configured.`

Then I started checking my DB connections, credentials and everything was fine on my machine, so I ssh'd into my Forge instance and wanted to check .env credentials and database configuration and I found no `database.php` in `config` folder. Then I checked the git repository to see if it existed there and it didn't.

I checked .gitignore in my app's root folder and none of the config files were being ignored.

So I went ahead and tried to add config/database.php manually by doing
`git add config/database.php` and it popped up with a message something along the lines of: `config/database.php` is being ignored by one of the .gitignore files.

I went through ALL the .gitignore files in EVERY single folder for about 20 times, LITERALLY! But couldn't find anything like that...

So... What kind of sorcery is this?

Comment: Are you _certain_ that one of the git ignore files does not have a restriction which would cause the file to be ignored?  I am willing to bet that a rule exists somewhere to this effect.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, because I had all the gitignore files open and going through them one by one, line by line.. plus it was a fresh laravel installation, so wouldn't make sense why it was doing that. In the end I used `git add -f config/database.php` and then it worked. I just wanted to double check here on StackOverflow that config/database.php definitely has to exist on the production too.

Comment: It should be there. Might be something in your global gitignore file: ```git config --global core.excludesfile```

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by your global gitignore file, usually found at `~/.gitignore_global`. The default values of mine were:

```
*~
.DS_Store
database.php
```

After removing the `database.php` entry, `config/database.php` finally got recognised for me.